# How to append/insert to TextView with retained format

Tags: java, android, string, formatting, textview

I have a code like this:

`strings.xml`

```
<string name="message1">Your money: <b>1000</b> <b>2000</b></string>
<string name="message2">Your money: <b>%1$s</b> <b>%2$s</b></string>
```

And I want to show it in a TextView

`MainActivity.java`

```
// This one will render 1000 and 2000 in bold correctly
TextView mText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message1);
mText1.setText(getText(R.string.message1));

// This one fail to render 1000 and 2000 in bold    
int val1 = 1000, val2 = 2000;
TextView mText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message2);
mText1.setText(String.format(getText(R.string.message2).toString(), val1, val2));
```

I want to make that I can format the text in bold/italic by applying String.format to android string resource.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take a look at android [string resource guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).
Section on **Styling with HTML markup** shows how to do this.

First you need to give your string resource as follows(html escape the opening html tags)

```
<string name="message2">Your money: &lt;b>%1$s&lt;/b> &lt;b>%2$s&lt;/b></string>
```

Then retrieve and format your string as follows

```
String text = getString(R.string.message2, val1, val2);
CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
mText2.setText(styledText);
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `Html.fromHtml` method

```
int val1 = 1000, val2 = 2000;
mText2.setText(Html.fromHtml("Your money:" +"<b>"+val1+"</b>:"+"<b>"+val2+"</b>:"));
```

Hope to help!